# Disable Hyper-v in windows 8.1 pro error

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am trying to disable Hyper-V in Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit but it is not working.
I tried using Control Panel as well as by using this command: `dism. exe /Online /Disable‐Feature: Microsoft‐Hyper‐V`

But did not work.

During shutdown it does up to 30% disables and during boot time it gives message as `Getting Windows ready ...% completed` and then it shows:

```
We couldn't complete the features
Undoing changes
Don't turn off your computer
```

How do I resolve this error? or how do I disable Hyper-V in  Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit?

Error files 
[OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2781DCEAE2700306!1247&authkey=!AOCks1Jcu0SwjAk&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: This can't be answered in general. Copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS, the file C:\Windows\WinSxS\poqexec.log and the file C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log to the desktop, compress them into a zip and share the zip (OneDrive, Dropbox, Google drive). I'll take a look at the logs to see what is wrong.

Comment: @magicandre1981 added zip files.

Comment: ok, I looked at the logs and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log shows that Windows fails to update the boot manager:

> **10:27:54, Error      [0x018050] CSI    0000004e (F) Failed execution
>   of queue item Installer: Boot Configuration CSI Advanced installer
>   ({3eca0b00-79bb-42b9-8421-a26a5cbb37e4}) with HRESULT
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).  Failure will not be
>   ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the
>   installer queue are completed; installer is reliable
>   (2)[gle=0x80004005]**

This happens when you use other boot manager like GRUB to dual boot Linux. Remove GRUB, uninstall Hyper-V and restore GRUB after doing it.

Comment: Do we have other solution to this problem ,I need to install Ubuntu again which will take few hrs .

Comment: ask here in a new question how to backup/restore GRUB without reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: nice to hear this :)