# How to backup/restore GRUB without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, backup, grub

I need to [remove grub to disable Hyper-v](https://superuser.com/a/857677/174557) . I couldn't find any solution to achieve this .As many solution exist to this but they doesn't satisfy requirement .

I would like remove grub and then again restore without loosing Ubuntu .

i.e. i don't want to do `remove ubuntu -> fix boot manager -> disable Hyper-v -> install Ubuntu-> install software/application in Ubuntu`instead i would like to have solution something like this `Remove grub -> disable Hyper-v -> restore grub .`

How to do this ?

OS:

Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit 
Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit 
Dual booted system .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove grub

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub

After you are done you need to reinstall grub :)

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please expand your answer by adding the essential elements from the links (you can copy and paste or just add a synopsis of the key points).  Thanks.